# ZF2 add styles to elements

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

Hi is there a way to add style to a form element, besides adding a class?

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
        'name' => 'notas',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Notas',
            'label_attributes' => array(
                'class'  => 'label-wrapped'
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way, But I still don't know how to add several styles

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
    'name' => 'notas',
    'attributes' => array(
        'style'=>'width:100px',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Notas',
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'class'  => 'label-wrapped'
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: By 'several styles' do you mean `style' => 'width:100px; height: 80px;'`?

Comment: @TimFountain I think he does. But I think a better way will be to get the form element in the view and set styles there.

Comment: I believe a better way is to use classes and avoid inline-css :)

Comment: Yes @TimFountain like that, some times I dont want add small css config, I dont want to create a class/css.